# My Contact Form is not sending Mail

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have uploded both files to server but when i submit a form the thanks message  comes but there no mail in my inbox. plz help me.

My Html Page is

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">

</tr>





<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have uploded both files to server but when i submit a form the thanks message  comes but there no mail in my inbox. plz help me.

My Php Coding Is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "anshu_mah@yahoo.co.in";

    $email_subject = "website form submissions";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: how you are submitting your form ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the mail is getting blocked by your incoming server because it looks like the sender is invalid, which appears similar to spam.

If you have access to it, check the filter log on your server.  This should be available in cPanel as "trace email".  If your mail is getting blocked you will see it in the list with a mark against it that indicates a problem, hover over that and you will see the reason.

If that is the case, and the reason is something like "sender verification failed", y ou might like to try the `-f` "envelope from address" additional parameter:

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, "-f $email_from");
```

Mail function reference, including note about "additional parameters" and specifically `-f` for sendmail:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass additional
>   flags as command line options to the program configured to be used
>   when sending mail, as defined by the sendmail_path configuration
>   setting. For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender
>   address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.
>
> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user
>   to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from
>   being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using
>   this method. For sendmail users, this file is /etc/mail/trusted-users.

Answer (score 0):

$email_to     = 'nobody@example.com';

$email_subject = 'the subject';

$email_message = 'hello';

$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .

```
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

Try this and let me know